# How can I run a function and return output as image src javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, function, src

I have a function that determines which source the image will be:

```
function facilityImg(arr, x) {
    switch (arr[x]) {
        case 'Yes':
            return "Images/checked.png";
        case 'No':
            return "Images/unchecked.png";
    }
}
```

Where `arr` is an array of Yes/No strings, and `x` is the index of each value.

I am trying to run this function like this:

```
let html = `<div class="facilityCell">
               <img class="facilityIcon" title="Air-Conditioner" src="Images/air-conditioner.png">
               <img class="facilityIcon" src='facilityImg(${facilityArr}, 0)'>
            </div>`
```

When inspecting the html element, I get this as the src:

[image: Output of the img src]

Is there something I am doing wrong? I have tried with `[src]` and `:src` which should apparently work. And before you shoot me down in the comments, I am repeating this code but slightly different each time for a minor project - cant be bothered to write out another 400 lines in the correct way.

Is what I am wanting to do possible?

Comment: Try this `src="${facilityImg(facilityArr, 0)}"`

Comment: @AHMEDSAJJAD kindly post it as an answer so can mark it as an answer, as it can help someone in future.

Comment: Posted it as an answer. @Elliot Cullen please accept it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to correct the interpolation of your function. Try

```
let html = `<div class="facilityCell">
              <img class="facilityIcon" title="Air-Conditioner" src="Images/air-conditioner.png">
              <img class="facilityIcon" src="${facilityImg(facilityArr, 0)}">
            </div>`
```

Hope that fixes it